# C# 2.0 Generic Tree containing multiple types

Tags: c#

I'm having a tricky time in thrashing out how best to approach this particular problem and would really like some guidance from the expert community!

Let's say I have 3 classes

```
Branch
Twig
Leaf
```

A `Branch` can contain a collection of other `Branch` objects, but can also contain a collection of `Twig` objects and a collection of `Leaf` objects.

A `Twig` can contain a collection of other `Twig` objects, but can also contain a collection of `Leaf` objects.

A `Leaf` object can be considered a base component and contains no collections of any other objects.

Hence, the possible stuctures are

**Branch**

```
Branch                Branch                  Branch
|                     |                       |
|_Branch              |_Twig                  |_Leaf
|  |_etc...           |  |_etc...
|                     |
|_Twig                |_Leaf
|  |_etc...
|
|_Leaf
```

**Twig**

```
Twig                  Twig
|                     |
|_Twig                |_Leaf
|  |_etc...
|
|_Leaf
```

**Leaf**

```
Leaf
```

Given a `Branch`, I would like to be able to interrogate any descendent `Branch`, `Twig`, or `Leaf` objects and know

1. The ratio that each descendent object contributes to the top object (the ratio is contextual to the parent and child object in each case).
2. If the descendent objects of a particular type contain a particular property value. For example, Check descendent `Leaf` objects to see if more than 4 have `UnderSide` property value `"Furry"`

I would also like to be able to have the options to

3.enumerate through the objects a descendent level at a time i.e. an ordered list of all first children, followed by all second children, etc (the order of objects in each level does not matter).

4. enumerate through the objects breadth-wise i.e. an ordered list of first child, and if first child has children then first child's children, then if that object has children then it's children ....then second child, etc...

My first thought is to use a generic tree and interface polymorphism, but I'm having difficulty in working out the details - `Twig` and `Leaf` objects share some common properties but `Branch` objects are very different. If I was dealing with only one type of object it would be very straightforward! Can this be done in a type-safe manner?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use interfaces to dictate who can hold what:

```
public interface IBranch { }
public interface ITwig { }

public class Branch : IBranch
{
    List<IBranch> _Kids = new List<IBranch>();
    public List<IBranch> Kids
    {
        get { return _Kids; }
    }
}

public class Twig : ITwig, IBranch
{
    List<ITwig> _Kids;
    public List<ITwig> Kids
    {
        get { return _Kids; }
    }
}

public class Leaf : ITwig, IBranch
{
}
```

implement ienumerable and make sure you "yield return this" before enumerating children.  it would be good to put all common functionality in IBranch, and commonality between leaf and twig in ITwig.

hope this helps!

Comment: This is the best solution. However, I think that you'd do a lot better going with "Root", "Branch" and "Leaf" for your three levels, rather than "Branch", "Twig", and "Leaf".

Answer (score 1):

They do all share the Ratio property though don't they, so you could at the very least have them all implement some IRatio interface...

Comment: The ratio isn't quite a property of each object itself - the ratio is a property of a node containing the object rather than the object itself - does that make sense? Let me know if my question description is misleading and I'll happily change it

Comment: For further info - the ratio of a child is contextual to the parent. Take a leaf object for example. In the db, a specific leaf id may be a child of more than one distinct twig - the ratio in each relatonship that the leaf contributes to the twig can be different

Comment: Aha, I get it, but then you have have treenodes (i.e. a containing datastructure) that contain either a Branch, a Twig or a Leaf, can't you traverse the containing tree datastructure and then based on the payload type calculate the ratio?

Comment: Coming up with the containing datastructure is the part that I'm wrestling with! How do I go about defining a tree structure that can take three different types? I'm thinking a node would need to inspect it's payload type to get the payload child objects and then construct a list of child nodes on itself, each containing a child object of the payload object. This operation would need to be recursive for inspecting the tree.

Comment: Just create a marker interface, INodePayload, decorate your classes with it, than, make sure that in your tree's nodes only objects decorated with that interface are allowed. The interface is just for identification purposes, it is empty. I you only have those 3 objects, just create your own treenode class and write logic handling each of the 3 cases..

Comment: if(payload.GetType() == typeof(Branch){}else if(Twig){}.. etc.

Comment: How would go about building the tree? Presumably, the Branch class has GetChildBranches(), GetChildTwigs() and GetChildLeaves() methods/accessors and the Twig class has GetChildTwigs() and GetChildLeaves(). How would you recurse through each payload type and build the child nodes?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would probably do it:

```
public interface INodeChild
{
    public INodeParent Parent {get;set;}
    //Any methods/properties common to ALL inheritors
}

public abstract class NodeParent : INodeChild
{
    public INodeParent Parent {get; protected set;}

    public IList<INodeChild> Children {get;set;}
    // This is just breadth-wise since I'm more familiar with that.
    public string ListChildren(int level)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(INodeChild item in Children)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(Enumerable.Repeat(" ", level));
            INodeParent itemParent = item as INodeParent;
            if(itemParent != null)
            {
                itemParent.ListChildren(++level);
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    //Any methods/properties common to all parent inheritors (brach/twig/etc)
}

public class Brach : NodeParent
{
    // Any branch only stuff goes here.
}

public class Twig : NodeParent
{
    // Any twig only stuff goes here
}

public class Leaf : INodeChild
{
    // Any leaf only stuff goes here.
}
```